# Disable ipv6 loopback

Tags: windows-server-2008, ipv6, loopback

I am trying to get the IPv6 loopback completely disabled/disconnected.  Searching the posts here I see everything that I have done so far.

1)Un-check the IPv6 on the adapter which will disable IPv6 for that LAN interface.

2)Add the DisabledComponents DWORD 000000ff

The Pre/Post reboot >netsh interface ipv6 show interface

PRE:

```
Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          50  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
 12          50        1280  disconnected  isatap.{08551F83-B9DE-4FF1-8A21-5B988
00BEC66}
 13          10        1280  connected     6TO4 Adapter
 14          50        1280  connected     Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
```

POST:

```
Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          50  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
```

3)Edited the hosts file to look like:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

So is there anything else I can do to disable/disconnect the IPv6 loopback?  Netsh still shows the loopback interface connected.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why? Are you just trying to disable IPv6 for the machine? Removing the capability from the NICs in question should mean that they don't talk IPv6 anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just unchecking the box doesn't completely disable ipv6.

c:>reg add hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\tcpip6\parameters /v DisabledComponents /t REG_DWORD /d 255

and unless you need ipv6, you should do this because it causes problems and muddies up your dns with all the entries

Comment: Item #2 that I listed does this.  255 = Dword  of 000000ff

Comment: Accepting this. 1/2 of the story.

Comment: Disabling IPv6 is the worst advise you can give. It's being deployed by many ISPs and websites (i.e. Google, Youtube, CNN, Yahoo, Bing, Facebook, etc) and Microsoft explicitly says that turning IPv6 off is an unsupported configuration because more and more internal Windows components are relying on it. From http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/magazine/2009.07.cableguy(en-us).aspx: "If IPv6 is disabled on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, or later versions, some components will not function."

Comment: For these particular servers at that time it made sense.  For different servers, and moving forward, removing IPv6 probably wont' for us.  These servers were for an internal dev environment.

Comment: according to documentation, this field allows disabling IPv6 for pretty much anything EXCEPT loopback. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852#letmefixit

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just `netsh interface ipv6>uninstall`? This shall remove the ipv6 support completely.

Comment: Because then IPv6 would be disabled, which just leads to additional problems in the future. This question really should have been clarified, but the poster never bothered.

Comment: I really did want to remove all IPv6 at the time.  These were some internal servers that will never need IPv6.